# How do I make a function work in a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, abstract-class, derived-class

So this is my code. It has an abstact class named PC and 3 derived classes named HomePC, GamingPC and WorkStationPC. It has to do 4 things: 1)Create new pc of whatever type, 2)Upgrade a pc that already exists, 3)Delete a pc that already exists and 4)Print all pcs of a certain type. I managed to make the "new" and "print" functions work. I can't figure out how to make the "upgrade" and "delete" functions work. I suppose they will be similar. If someone has an idea of how I can do it please let me know.

Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class PC{
protected:
    string operatingSystem;
    int ramSlots;
    int pcieSlots;
    int cpu;
    int totalRamSlots;
    int gbPerRam;
    int ssd;
    int cost;
public:
    virtual void Print() = 0;
    virtual void Upgrade(string opt) = 0;

    PC(string OS, int moboRam, int moboPcie, int numOfCores, int ramSlots, int ramGB, int ssdGB, int pcCost){
        operatingSystem = OS;
        ramSlots = moboRam;
        pcieSlots = moboPcie;
        cpu = numOfCores;
        totalRamSlots = ramSlots;
        gbPerRam = ramGB;
        ssd = ssdGB;
        cost = pcCost;      
    }
};

class HomePC: public PC{
private:
    string model;
public:
    HomePC(string OS, int moboRam, int moboPcie, int numOfCores, int ramSlot, int ramGB, int ssdGB, int pcCost, string mdl):PC(OS, moboRam, moboPcie, numOfCores, ramSlot, ramGB, ssdGB, pcCost){
        model = mdl;        
    }

    void set_totalRamSlots(int ramSlots){totalRamSlots = ramSlots;}
    void set_gbPerRam(int ramGB){gbPerRam = ramGB;}
    void set_cpu(int numOfCores){cpu = numOfCores;}

    //delete spaces

    void Print(){ cout << "Μodel: " << model << endl << "Operating System: MacOS" <<endl << "Motherboard: 2 RAM slot(s), 0 GPU slot(s)" << endl << "CPU: " << cpu << endl << "RAM: " << totalRamSlots << " stick(s), " << gbPerRam << " GigaBytes" << endl << "SSD: 256" << endl << "Cost: 800EUR" << endl;}
    void Upgrade(string opt){ cout << opt << endl;}

    //delete spaces

    string get_model() const {return model;}
};

class GamingPC: public PC{
private:
    string model;
    int gpu;
public:
    GamingPC(string OS, int moboRam, int moboPcie, int numOfCores, int ramSlot, int ramGB, int ssdGB, int pcCost, int numOfGpus, string mdl):PC(OS, moboRam, moboPcie, numOfCores, ramSlot, ramGB, ssdGB, pcCost){
        model = mdl;
        gpu = numOfGpus;
    }

    //delete spaces

    void set_totalRamSlots(int ramSlots){totalRamSlots = ramSlots;}
    void set_gbPerRam(int ramGB){gbPerRam = ramGB;}
    void set_cpu(int numOfCores){cpu = numOfCores;}
    void set_gpu(int numOfGpus){gpu = numOfGpus;}

    //delete spaces

    void Print(){ cout << "Μodel: " << model << endl << "Operating System: MacOS" << endl << "Motherboard: 4 RAM slot(s), 2 GPU slot(s)" << endl << "CPU: " << cpu << endl << "RAM: "<< totalRamSlots << " stick(s), " << gbPerRam << " GigaBytes" << endl << "SSD: 256" << endl << "GPU: " << gpu << endl << "Cost: 1300EUR" << endl;}
    void Upgrade(string opt){ cout << opt << endl;}

    //delete spaces

    string get_model() const {return model;}
};

class WorkStationPC: public PC{
private:
    string model;
    int gpu;
    bool afterburner;
public:
    WorkStationPC(string OS, int moboRam, int moboPcie, int numOfCores, int ramSlot, int ramGB, int ssdGB, int pcCost, int numOfGpus, bool aburner, string mdl):PC(OS, moboRam, moboPcie, numOfCores, ramSlot, ramGB, ssdGB, pcCost){
        model = mdl;
        gpu = numOfGpus;
        afterburner = aburner;
    }

    //delete spaces

    void set_totalRamSlots(int ramSlots){totalRamSlots = ramSlots;}
    void set_gbPerRam(int ramGB){gbPerRam = ramGB;}
    void set_cpu(int numOfCores){cpu = numOfCores;}
    void set_gpu(int numOfGpus){gpu = numOfGpus;}
    void set_afterburner(int aburner){afterburner = aburner;}

    //delete spaces

    void Print(){ cout << "Μodel: " << model << endl << "Operating System: MacOS" << endl << "Motherboard: 8 RAM slot(s), 1 GPU slot(s)" << endl << "CPU: " << cpu << endl << "RAM: " << totalRamSlots << " stick(s), " << gbPerRam << " GigaBytes" << endl << "SSD: 256" << endl << "GPU: " << gpu << endl << "Afterburner: " << afterburner << endl << "Cost: 1600EUR" << endl;}
    void Upgrade(string opt){ cout << opt << endl;}

    //delete spaces

    string get_model() const {return model;}
};



int main(){
    vector<int> count_homepc;
    vector<int> count_gamingpc;
    vector<int> count_workstationpc;
    int i, k = 0;
    string input, opCode, key=" ", pcType, pcModel, data[5];
    size_t pos = 0;
    vector<PC*> pcList;
    do{
        cout << "---Enter an operation:" << endl;
        getline(cin,input);
        pos=input.find(key);
        opCode=input.substr(0,pos);
        input.erase(0,pos + 1);
        if(opCode=="new"){
            pos=input.find(key);
            pcType=input.substr(0,pos);
            input.erase(0,pos + 1);
            pcModel=input;
            if(pcType=="homepc"){
                HomePC* myPC = new HomePC("MacOS", 2, 0, 2, 1, 4, 256, 800, pcModel);
                pcList.push_back(myPC);
                count_homepc.push_back(k);
            }else if(pcType=="gamingpc"){
                GamingPC* myPC = new GamingPC("Windows", 4, 2, 6, 2, 8, 1024, 1300, 1, pcModel);
                pcList.push_back(myPC);
                count_gamingpc.push_back(k);
            }else if(pcType=="workstationpc"){
                WorkStationPC* myPC = new WorkStationPC("Linux", 8, 1, 6, 4, 16, 2048, 1600, 0, 0, pcModel);
                pcList.push_back(myPC);
                count_workstationpc.push_back(k);
            }else cout << "Wrong PC type, try again." << endl;
        }else if(opCode=="upgrade"){
            pos=input.find(key);
            pcModel=input.substr(0,pos);
            input.erase(0,pos + 1);
            cout << input << endl;
        }else if(opCode=="delete"){ 
            cout << "WIP" << endl;
        }else if(opCode=="print"){
            cout << endl;
            int point;
            if(input=="homepc"){
                for(i=0;i<count_homepc.size();i++){
                    point = count_homepc[i];
                    pcList[point]->Print();
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }else if(input=="gamingpc"){
                for(i=0;i<count_gamingpc.size();i++){
                    point = count_gamingpc[i];
                    pcList[point]->Print();
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }else if(input=="workstationpc"){
                for(i=0;i<count_workstationpc.size();i++){
                    point = count_workstationpc[i];
                    pcList[point]->Print();
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }else if(opCode!="q") cout << "Wrong operation, try again." << endl;
        k++;
    }while(opCode!="q"); //when someone inputs the string "q" the loop ends
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you seem to have forgotten a virtual destructor in your PC class, that is needed if you inherit from it.

Comment: @AndersK To be pedantic: A virtual destructor is only needed if you ever `delete` the object via a base class pointer.

Answer (score 0):

## Delete

Seems like u keep the name of the pc in a member called `model`. First thing to do is to remove it from all the 3 derived classes and put it in the base `PC` class. This is where it belongs. Every pc must have a name. U have 4 things to do:

- read `PC` name
- search for it in vector
- actually delete the `PC`
- erase the `PC` pointer from the vector

```cpp
// "name" is the name of target "PC"
for(auto i = 0; i < pcList.size(); i++)
    if(pcList[i]->model == name) {
        delete pcList[i];
        pcList.erase(pcList.begin() + i);
        break;
    }
```

U could set up a `auto found = false` and set it to true when the `PC` was found, so u know if there was actually a `PC` with that name

## Upgrade

This one is a bit more complex as u have to pass multiple stuff. One way to achieve this is just to take one part at a time by setting a loop. Everytime u're in the loop u can select which part u wanna upgrade, or to exit. This would look like:

```cpp
std::cin >> pc; // Pos in vector
while(true) {
    // 1: upgrade cpu
    // 2: upgrade ram
    // ...
    // 0: finish
    int option;
    std::cin >> option;
    if(option == cpu) { // "cpu" should be a constant. In this case is integer "1"
        int cpu; // The new cpu goes here
        std::cin >> cpu;
        pcList[pc]->cpu = cpu;
        // pcList[pc]->upgradeCpu(cpu); // If u wanna do it OOP. Same as the line before
        // I see u have "set_cpu()" and more fcts for that. Use them
    }
    // Repeat here for every upgradable part of a pc
    else if(option == exit)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Also, can you upgrade a HomePC to a GamingPC, which is tricky to do as you probably have to copy it and add to the relevant vector then delete the old one.

Comment: I guess the classes are gonna become more complex later. U can make a `GamingPC` constructor which takes as argument an `HomePC*` and copies the relevant fields to itself

Comment: So, I guess I had to make it more specific. The delete operation has to be inputed like this: delete (pcModel) , where pcModel is the name of the pc that the user inputed when they used the new operation. So for example if someone inputs this command: new gamingpc myPC, that means that a new pc must be created as a gamingpc with the name of myPC and if later the user inputs: delete myPC, the pc must be deleted.

Comment: Also, if the pcType is homepc then the upgrade function has to be inputed like this: upgrade pcModel cpu_cores number_of_ram_sticks GB_per_ram, if the pcType is gamingpc then the upgrade function has to be inputed like this: upgrade pcModel cpu_cores number_of_ram_sticks GB_per_ram number_of_GPUs, and if the pcType is workstationpc then the upgrade function has to be inputed like this: upgrade pcModel cpu_cores number_of_ram_sticks GB_per_ram number_of_GPUs afterburner. So we have a string of all the numbers we need to implement into the pcModel pc all the different numbers.

Comment: I have made changes to my post so it fits your requirements

Comment: U know when an upgrade operation is active. U need to do a similar search for the `PC`, and based on its type u decide how much stuff to read from input and what to set. Idt there is a must to make separate function for this stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can delete or upgrade based on a unique ID you give to each PC. That way you can have multiple PCs with the same model and same names. This ID could be the index of the pcList vector given for that pc when pushed into that vector. When the user input the operation "new" and a pc you can output pcList.size() which will be given as an ID to the new PC. And when the user wants to upgrade or delete he has to specify the ID of the pc he wants to modify